# GIT Push Errors - Duplicate Request

Tags: git

New to GIT and facing the below issue when pushing local branch changes to master.
Any help appreciated

! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/master (duplicate request)
error: failed to push some refs to < some SSH site >

Answer (score 36):

The issue is evident from the error message itself.

execute `git log` and you should notice two different commits for the same changes. i.e. Change Id will be same for different commit ids.

You should revert latest duplicate commit and merge the same with existing one.

Use the following commands for solution.

```
 git reset --soft HEAD^
 git status
 git commit --amend
```

Now try to push the changes 'git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master'

Comment: When I tried step 1, I got a fatal message that it was an ambiguous argument HEAD, it turns out my branch was ahead by 3 commits. I ran  "git reset --soft HEAD~1" 3 times before I could move on.

Answer (score 2):

Chances are, there may be new changes on the remote that you do not yet have in your local repository.  You may want to either `git pull --rebase` or `git pull` followed by a merge before attempting to `git push` again.

Comment: "git pull --rebase" has been performed before doing "git push". There is a code review in Gerrit to which the changes are being pushed with the same "change-id". Would this cause an issue.

Comment: Important to understand the "git-review" behavior, in terms of which branch it gets merged to, once review-done-and-accepted. Most cases, it will be "master". Hence, if the remote "master" has moved ahead, from where you would have re-based and started working, then you need to pull the latest changes on master, and thence re-base to this latest (validate your changes with test cases), and then "git review" will work for you branch changes.